# How to visualise a large correlation matrix?

Tags: pandas, correlation

I have a dataset with 24 variables, 21 of them numeric. As part of model building I decided to look into the correlation between features and so what I get is a large correlation matrix (21 * 21).

Now visualising such large matrices becomes a very messy task and you end up hurting your eyes. So what I have done is set a threshold and to slice out those rows that have greater than this value (say 0.60). However, I'm getting a matrix that has now several NaNs. When I try to drop these null values, the matrix loses all data and what I'm left is a 0*0 matrix.

```py
corr_matrix = data.corr()

threshold = 0.60

high_corr = corr_matrix.loc[corr_matrix >= 0.60]

high_corr.dropna(inplace=True)

print(high_corr)
Empty DataFrame
Columns = []
```

Visualising the matrix with nans is a good idea but it also results in empty squares. I'm looking for a way where only those rows that have values >= threshold are retained, with no nans. That would make a much smaller matrix which is much less messier when plotted in matplotlib. However I haven't been able to code it that way; can anyone suggest some strategies to deal with such large matrices?

Comment: Have you considered colorizing the matrix in the style of a heatmap, rather than poring over the numerical values? Your current approach won't help much if you find that there's high correlation among all features and can't drop any. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286607/making-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (note that I didn't add error checking, so it'll crash if your threshold removes all values). Also, I made it an *absolute* high pass rather than a normal high pass because I assume you'd be interested in strong negative correlation as well? If you're not, just remove the `abs()` in the filter function.

```
from numpy.random      import randn
from pandas            import DataFrame
from seaborn           import heatmap
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
from itertools         import combinations

def absHighPass(df, absThresh):
    passed = set()
    for (r,c) in combinations(df.columns, 2):
        if (abs(df.loc[r,c]) >= absThresh):
            passed.add(r)
            passed.add(c)
    passed = sorted(passed)
    return df.loc[passed,passed]

labels = [chr(x) for x in range(65,91)]
corrDf = DataFrame(randn(26,26), index=labels, columns=labels).corr()

#heatmap(corrDf,cmap="YlGnBu")
heatmap(absHighPass(corrDf,0.5),cmap="YlGnBu")
show()
```

This is the filtered heatmap:

[image: filtered]

And this is another run but with the unfiltered heatmap:

[image: unfiltered]

Comment: Impressive. I'll certainly try this out.